# Algorithm for clustering substrings by indexrange in string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, cluster-analysis

Is there an effective algorithm to find clusters of groups (substring, index 40-45) by their position? Groups that are close together should be in one cluster.
For example:

> *Lorem Ipsum is **simply** dummy **text** of **the printing** and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
> scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
> five centuries, but also the **leap** into electronic typesetting,
> remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
> the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
> more recently with desktop **publishing software** like **Aldus** **PageMaker**
> including versions of Lorem Ipsum*

I marked random words in this example, its only about clustering these groups.

In this example, the algorithm should group [simply, text, the printing], [leap], [publishing software, Aldus PageMaker]. I got the start- and the end index of each group. My approach was to define a maximum distance between  a single group of characters to be included in on cluster. Is there any algorithm that solves this kind of problem?

Comment: To be honest: I don't think so. First of all, the results you want are rather arbitrary (why is industry's standard dummy text not a match?) It's not just about finding the subject of a sentence but also some sort of filtering which you didn't describe. So even your requirement is already flawed, and for such requirements, no algorithm exists.

Comment: i already have the algorithm to find the specific groups. I marked random words in this example. The algorithm that i was looking for should only cluster groups, not find them. Maybe my question was misleading

Comment: Can you provide some code? Since you specified the language, then how the input text would be stored and more important how you expect selected words to be "marked" (in Java) ? Try to describe your vision of the algorithm at least in pseudocode or plain words.